# Regular Expression through VB Script

Tags: regex, vbscript

I Have on Text file. file containing like below

### File:

```
hello:all\hareesh\ _is very bad boy

hello:all\sampath _good fellow

hello:all\hareesh\going to office very late

hello:all\Jithendra is hero

hello:all\hareesh\ _is going on vacation 

hello:all\hareesh\ _is worst fellow

hello:all\Suresh_india

hello:all\hareesh\ _jaffa
```

so what i want do is print lines if line containing hareesh_ so ignore remaining cases

so my output should be (Note: don't come spaces in between words

### output:

```
hello:all\hareesh\ _is very bad boy

hello:all\hareesh\ _is going on vacation 

hello:all\hareesh\ _is worst fellow

hello:all\hareesh\ _jaffa
```

### my code is:

```
Const ForReading = 1

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

objRegEx.Global = True   

objRegEx.Pattern =".{0,}" &"\b" & "hareesh" & "[^;0-9a-zA-z-~\-_=+']" & ".{0,}\n"

objRegEx.Ignorecase = true


Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\Hareesh\Desktop\EPB\Hari.txt", ForReading)

strTargetText = objFile.ReadAll

objFile.Close

Set colMatches = objRegEx.Execute(strTargetText)   

If colMatches.Count > 0 Then

   For Each strMatch in colMatches  

       strText = strText & strMatch.Value 

   Next

End If

Wscript.Echo strText
```

Please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: add a lookahead if there is one available in VB.Something like (?=.*?hareesh.*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.*?hareesh\\?\s*_.*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/_u4MTIsuqLfjDy05)